# Replace values in a string

Tags: python, join, split

So the challenge was to replace a specific word in a sentence with asterisks with equivalent length to that word - 3 letters --> 3 asterisks etc.

Section One does not work, but Section Two does - can anyone critique Section One and maybe point out the possible mistake I was making, as the logic seemed sound originally?

```
def censor(text, word):
  for c in text:
    if c == word:                         ## this line was totally wrong
      text.replace(c, "*" * len(c))
    return text
```

The next segment does work, then CodeAcademy's answer was way different:

```
def censor(text, word):
  a = "*" * len(word)
  for c in text:
    nw = text.split(word)
  return a.join(nw)
```

How would you approach this task?

Comment: Is `text` a list or a string?

Comment: Hint. Consider the code `x = "Hello"; x.replace("H", "J"); print(x)`. What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: What is your concrete question (you shouldn't really be asking for our opinions - these vary)? What's the expected input and output. Please take a look at [mcve]. Also, what values are getting passed into `text` and `word`? It seems that you're iterating over characters in text and comparing them to words.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm use this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Also, you should ask one question per question. Asking multiple questions makes your question less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution is not perfect either:

```
def censor(text, word):
  a = "*" * len(word)
  nw = text.split(word)  # no need for a loop here, one split catches all occurrences
  return a.join(nw)
```

For your first attempt:

```
def censor(text, word):
  # for c in text:  # loops char by char
  #  if c == word:  # one character likely won't be your word
  #    text.replace(c, "*" * len(c))  # does nothing, string is immutable
  return text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))  # simple!
```

Comment: It's probably a Good Idea for the first task to split on whitespace and do the replacement in a loop, so you don't perform replacements on words that contain the target word, as in Doncho Gunchev's 'air' - 'airplane' example.

Comment: Didn't realise the loop mistake in part one - I must have thought I still needed to iterate through it some way. Glad to see I wasn't too far off with the text.replace(c, "*" * len(c)) in part one - makes more sense now that I know I was looping through chars. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code you iterate over the string character by character - you will never find a word.

I'd use regular expression `import re` in that case to make it faster and find the proper word. Try masking the word 'air' in the sentence `The airplane is in the air now!`.

Example with `re`.

```
re.sub(r'\bair\b', '***', 'The airplane is in the air now!', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: What makes you think that regex would be faster for this task? The OP is doing a simple string replace operation, they don't need regex for that.

Comment: Finding the "word" correctly is difficult at best without regular expressions... Compiled regular expressions are fast and correct, but slower than the simple (incorrect) string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = "hello, how are you?"
word = "hello"
import re
final_string = re.sub("\b"+re.escape(word)+"\b", '*'*len(word), s)
```

Output:

```
'*****, how are you?'
```

Comment: You need `\b` around `word` to match properly. Also, `re.escape(word)`, not just word. Escaping is important, or you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection :-)

Comment: @DonchoGunchev thank you for pointing that out. I did not know that Python `re` was vulnerable to code injection

Comment: You can get RegExp injection, what if `word = '.'` or `word = '.*'`? The worst I can think of is a complex pattern that takes hours to match/not match... so DOS. Rule of thumb: if there are special characters - escape them (html, js, re, sql, you_name_it)!

Answer (score 0):

The regex approach is good. Another way would be to split the sentence by spaces, look for the word to censor, and replace it by asterisk.

```
def censor(sentence, word):
    return " ".join([w if w != word else "*"*len(w) for w in sentence.split(" ")])
```

Though, this wouldn't work with punctuation.