# Replacing a word in a string in python 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that will replace a word in a sentence (which are two separate strings) with "-". It works but I can figure out how to use len to make it so that it will print the correct amount of dashes for the number of characters in the word.

I have been using str.replace() but I can't figure out how to properly work in len(word) into the function so that it will print the correct number of dashes.

```
sentance=("what is tomorrow's date?")
word="what"

def replaceWord():
        print (sentance.replace(word,"----",))

replaceWord()
```

Comment: A trick: you can multiply a string by a number: `'-' * 5` == `"-----"`. So, replace that `5` with `len(word)` and you get the right number of dashes.

Comment: sentance.replace(word,"-" * len(word))

Comment: I saw two people answered this but got downvoted without any valid comments.... fishy... didn't like it at all....

Comment: @Abdurrahim possibly the downvotes were for posting code with no explanation (I didn't downvote, but I can see the deleted answers). If you suspect foul play, you can raise a mod flag on the question and explain your suspicions.

Comment: then those people should start writing comments about what they are disagreeing with. As you know stackoverflow allows editing so they may have a chance to improve their answers. But this behavior is discouraging people from answering in the first place

Comment: looks like duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918010/replace-values-in-a-string

Comment: I tried a bunch of different combinations of code and functions to try to figure this out but I just posted that basic code just so that people could have an idea of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def replaceWord(s, w):
    word_len = len(w)
    dashes = '-' * word_len
    print(s.replace(w,dashes));

s = "what is tomorrow's date?"
w = "what"
replaceWord(s, w)
```

In python, is possible to multiply a string for a number to obtain that string repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You have already got your answer. But, here I give you another way to achieve your goal. In this way, you can delibaretly choose your own separtor (e.g '-', '*', '/', etc.).

```
def replaceWord(sep, word, sentence):
    """
        :param sep: That is the separator.
        :param word: That is the work to replace.
        :param sentence: That is the sentence.
    """
    len_word = len(word)
    replacer = sep * len_word
    print(sentence.replace(word, replacer))

sentence = "what is tomorrow's date?"
word = "what"
sep = "-"  # you can change it
replaceWord(sep, word, sentence)
```

> **Output:**

```
---- is tomorrow's date?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the dash string for the len of the word like this

```
dash = '-'
wl = len(word)
string_to_replace = dash * wl
```